# Server Side Rendering Angular 2 in ASP.NET with Edge.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, edge.js, angular-universal

I'm exploring the possibility of rendering Angular 2 on the server side using Edge.js in an ASP.NET MVC application.

I'm aware that the Angular Universal Starter Kit has part of this equation: https://github.com/alexpods/angular2-universal-starter

However, it is using a Node.js server. I'd rather not add a Node.js server as an extra web server on top of the existing IIS server. My thought is I can perform the rendering of the Angular on the server side using Edge.js (i.e., to run the necessary JavaScript to generate the markup).

I am very new to Angular 2, so getting an example up and running is non-trivial for me. Based on this closed issue, I'd say there is currently no effort being made to add support for Edge.js (though it was being considered at one point): https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/40

**Does anybody know if rendering Angular on the server side using Edge.js from an ASP.NET MVC app is possible?**

By the way, I'm stuck on .NET 4.5.2 (Umbraco requires it), so I can't move to .NET Core and make use of this: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

Comment: I'm doing research here, but it's slow going: https://github.com/Nicholas-Westby/angular-2-lab

Comment: Hey Nicholas! We keep forgetting to rename the "examples" in the Universal repo to just playground, those are a mess, mainly there so we can just manually test changes we make to Universal and other modules.

Comment: But ya the key on the server-side is somehow invoking a Node process that passes Origin & Url (since we need to know where they are `/` `/home` etc, so we can render the correct section. But yea, you call platformNodeDynamic.serializeModule passing a Zone wrapped NgModule of your application. https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/blob/master/Client/bootstrap-server.ts

Comment: If you can figure out how to invoke a Node process in the same process (make sure you can capture any errors from it etc) let me know, I can help guide you in the right direction!

Comment: @MarkPieszak I got Node to run from the server, but I'm stuck on an error message that says "reflect metadata shim is required when using class decorators": https://github.com/Nicholas-Westby/angular-2-lab/issues/1

Comment: FYI, the new error I'm getting is "platformNodeDynamic is not a function": https://github.com/Nicholas-Westby/angular-2-lab/issues/1#issuecomment-261670134

Comment: You're using an old version of Node/NPM, get the latest Node 7.1. That's the reflect-metadata issue

Comment: With Core we start with an MVC TagHelper (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/2ba5a0ac930a055acc6e711a701ed43aa993ec8b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/Prerendering/PrerenderTagHelper.cs#L15) then we're in .NET land, that's where you want to call your EdgeJS, to invoke universal from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpaServices package from Microsoft. Internally this package will forward call to node server, but You won't have to run node on top of your asp.net core server.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
{
    options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.bundle.js";
    options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
        ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr")
        : null;
    options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
});

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
}
});
```

See more in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#drawbacks-of-ssr